# How can I add a join function to multiple ng-show items?

Tags: angularjs

I have four conditional ng-show elements:

```
Add
<strong ng-show="current_user.candidate.skills.length == 0">skills,</strong>
<strong ng-show="current_user.candidate.roles.length == 0">roles,</strong>
<strong ng-show="current_user.candidate.projects.length == 0">projects,</strong>
<strong ng-show="current_user.candidate.qualifications.length == 0">qualifications,</strong>
to increase your chances.
```

I want to add a .join(', ') function rather than have the commas after each item. I'd also like to add an 'and' between the last two items if items >= 2. What's the most Angular way to do this?

Comment: @Ezra, better edit the question instead of a comment

Comment: ng-show is not like ng-repeat that's why you would put them manually.

Comment: So if you were using ng-repeat what would you do in that case?

Comment: I've got an ngrepeat working for the comma seperated list. But now need to recreate the ng-show functionality. `%strong{"ng-repeat" => "(key, value) in candidate_values"}
          {{value}}{{$last ? '' : ($index==candidate_values.length-2) ? ' and ' : ', '}}`